# How to address overplotting in GGally::ggpairs()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, ggally

I'm using the `ggpairs()` function from the `GGally` package, but I'm having an issue dealing with overplotting.

Is there a good way to address the overplotting? I've tried setting the alpha value but I couldn't find out how to pass it to `ggpairs()`. I also looked into using `geom_hex` but again, I couldn't see how to use it with `ggpairs()`.

Here's a simple example:

```
# Create example data
df <- data.frame(x1=rnorm(1e4),
             x2=rnorm(1e4),
             x3=runif(1e4))

# Pairs plot
GGally::ggpairs(df)
```

[image]

Comment: This question covers how to set alpha in GGally, but not the broader question of the best way to deal with overplotting

Comment: not sure whether to vote to close this as a duplicate *"I've tried setting the alpha value...*" or needs more focus "*Is there a good way to address the overplotting*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce overplotting of the points you may modify the `size` aesthetic in `point` based layers displayed in the lower triangular of the plot matrix:

```r
GGally::ggpairs(df, lower=list(continuous=GGally::wrap("points", size = .01)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Also good to note that the same code can be used to set `alpha` instead of `size`. I had success using both.